# Can the getClass() method be used to access static variables?

Tags: java, class, static-variables

Consider this code:

```
class A {
    static int i=3;
}

public class TT extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new A().getClass().i);
    }
}
```

Can the `getClass()` method be used to access static variables in this context?

Comment: Just use A.i to get the static member.

Answer (score 9):

Not like that, no. `getClass()` returns a `Class<?>`, and `i` isn't a member of `Class`. You could use `getClass()` *followed by reflection* to get the field value, but it's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve here - when in the example you've given (which is all we've got to go by) simply using `A.i` would be simpler and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this code answers your question:

```
package com.cc.test;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class theClass = Class.forName("com.cc.test.TestMain$MyClass");
        Field theField = theClass.getField("myField");
        int theValue = theField.getInt(null); // null only works if myField is static
        System.out.println(theValue); // prints 99
    }

    private static class MyClass {
        public static int myField = 99;
    }
}
```